vs code does not load extensions on Starlink
Every time I am connected to my homes Starlink wifi and try to search for new extensions or load the recommended extensions it gives me the error, "error while fetching extensions.(failed to fetch)".Then when I connect to a non Starlink wifi network elsewhere then the extensions work.Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?
It has been causing me a lot of stress as I have been trying to figure this out for the past month. I have tried running a VPN turning on and off my Firewall and nothing works.
p.s. I am running vs code on a MacBook Air m3

Sounds like you should contact your ISP. This is a network problem.

Ok I’ll try that.
